# Summation Induction when lower limit is not 1

Tags: summation, induction

The question is use induction to prove that

$$\sum_{r=2}^n (r^2+r+1)r! = (n+1)^2n!-4$$

I don't understand how to even get the P1 statement since when I substitute r = 2 into the LHS and n = 1 into the RHS, I get LHS = 14 and RHS = 0.

Are my substitutions wrong?

Comment: An example substitution would be $n = 2$. Then the left hand side is just $(2^2 + 2 + 1)2! = 7\cdot2 = 14$. Meanwhile, the right hand side is $(2+1)^2 2! - 4 = 9\cdot2 - 4 = 18 - 4 = 14$. So the two sides are equal as desired.

Comment: In that case, do I use a P2 as a base statement instead of P1?

Comment: Demonstrated above is what happens when $n = 2$. Now suppose the identity holds when $n = k$ (this is your "induction hypothesis" or "IH"). Assuming your IH, can you show that the identity holds when $n = k+1$?

Comment: If I am understanding what you mean by P2 vs P1: Yes. You can think of this as induction starting at 2, or think of it as induction for some statement Q(n) defined to be P(n+1); then you are performing induction beginning at 1, i.e., for Q1, as is standard with such proofs. Such an argument will work for P(n+1) beginning with n = 1, i.e., beginning with P2.

Comment: Also $n=1$ works. Then LHS is *empty sum* hence equals $0$. So does RHS.

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you for your help!

Comment: It appears I did not realize that LHS is an empty sum all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Without induction,

$$(r^2+r+1)\cdot r!=\{(r+2)(r+1)-2(r+1)-1\}\cdot r!$$
$$=(r+2)!-(r+1)!-\{(r+1)!-r!\}$$

Telescoping Series!!

Comment: From what I understand from your reply, you first complete the square then prove it via method of differences. But is there a way to solve it with induction? Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: @manhatten, No. As $r^2+r+1$ is quadratic, write it is as $$(r+2)(r+1)+A(r+1)+B$$ then find $A,B$

Comment: $(r^2+r+1)\cdot r!=(r+1)\cdot(r+1)!-r\cdot r!$